# Скомпилированная программа не запускается

Tags: python

Есть код, который работает (в pycharm как минимум) но после того как я его скомпилировал, черный акран на секудну появляеться и закрываеться. Не могу понять почему

```
import re, pyperclip

    phoneNumber = re.compile(r'''(
         (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?
         (\s|\.|-)?
         (\d{3})
         (\s|\.|-)
         (\d{4})
         (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?
         )''', re.VERBOSE)
    
    email = re.compile(r'''(
         [a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+
         @
         [a-zA-Z0-9.]+
         (\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})
         )''', re.VERBOSE)
    
    text = str(pyperclip.paste())
    matches = []
    for groups in phoneNumber.findall(text):
        phoneNumber = '-'.join([groups[1], groups[3], groups[5]])
        if groups[6] != '':
            phoneNumber += ' x' + groups[6]
        matches.append(phoneNumber)
    for groups in email.findall(text):
        matches.append(groups[0])
    if len(matches) > 0:
        pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(matches))
        print('\n'.join(matches))
    else:
        print('don\'t find')
```

заранее благодарен

Comment: Запустите exe файл через cmd увидите в чем ошибка.

Comment: @Kers Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
[10996] Failed to execute script main  - такая ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать exe командой

```bsh
pyinstaller --noupx --onefile --noconsole script.py
```

`script.py` соответственное Ваш файл со скриптом.

Если вы собираете проект в виртуальном окружении то и ***pyinstaller должен быть в этом же окружении***

P.S. В случае с pyqt может потребовать указать path. Как пример `pyinstaller --noupx --onefile --noconsole --path PATH_TO_VENV\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin script.py`. С нюансами работы pyperclip не сталкивался но может пригодится.